# Matrix Table in Visual Force

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

I am trying to create a visualforce matrix chart that looks some thing like this..

I would like to have it set that the columns and row headers are set, but want to have the other field editable.  I will then create reports that look like this as well.  Where is says PSI maybe have that editable as well.  Do you have any suggestions on how to build this?
[image: Matrix Table]